# How to remove bar shadow in jqPlot bar chart

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart, shadow

I have a bar chart where at some point x-axis shows 35+ items representing individual bar on the chart.

[image]

**Problem:** Keeping the chart background size as currently it is, each bar becomes very narrow and displayed with the shadow which creates visual distraction. So I am trying to remove the SHADOWs from the chart.

**Tried:** Using shadow:false but it did not work. Shadow/shade is still there in every bar.

```
        grid:{
        background: '#f8f8f8'
        ,shadow:false
        }
```

The rest of the chart rendering code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/byg05bq2/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `shadow:false` parameter can be set on the bars as well. In the example you provided you only turned it off for the grid. See http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html. It will show you how to turn shadow off for the bars as well.

Comment: Just to be more specific, shadowOffset: 0 will remove the shadow
seriesDefaults: {
        rendererOptions: {
            shadowOffset: 0,   
        }
    },